# SIBER package error in createSiberObject - missing value where TRUE FALSE needed

Tags: r, dataframe, transform

I'm running some code in R for my master project and have hit an error I can't seem to work around,
Im using the SIBER package trying to transform my data to a SIBER object

When i run:

```
#Transform to siber object
siber.data <- createSiberObject(data)
```

I receive this error:

```
Error in if (xi > xj) 1L else -1L : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In xtfrm.data.frame(x) : cannot xtfrm data frames
2: In xtfrm.data.frame(x) : cannot xtfrm data frames
3: In Ops.factor(xi, xj) : ‘>’ not meaningful for factors
```

I think this means it is picking up some data as non-numeric? But when I check my data frame its all in numerical form? There are negatives and decimals in the data frame, would this cause this error?

I've tried to run traceback to find the source of the issue but I don't understand it either.

Comment: please provide an example of your data set, using `dput()` in order to make your error reproducible. Roughly, it looks like your data has missing values and factor variables, neither of which it seems that function allows.

Comment: I realised my data was in a tibble format not a dataframe which was responsible for the error.

Answer (score 0):

My data was in a tibble format instead of a dataframe, I had the dplyr package downloaded which caused this.
I just used

```
data <- as.data.frame(data)
siber.data <- createSiberObject(data)
```

this fixed the error!
Hope this helps someone